# Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём разница между реализациями функции queryFirst?

Tags: функции, kotlin, realm, inline

[image]

Вроде первая - высшего порядка, а вторая inline, но почему реализации именно такие - не понимаю

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Добавьте ваш код текстом.

Comment: Так и нет разницы, кроме того что одна inline, а вторая обычная.